# What does the return type string|((args: ValidationArguments) => string) return?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is taken from [line 107 here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/master/src/validation/ValidationTypes.ts#L107).  I think what this means is:

> This function returns a string or a function that takes `ValidationArguments` as an argument and then returns a string.

But it's the first time I have ever seen something like this, so just want to make sure I'm reading it right?

```
static getMessage(type: string, isEach: boolean): string|((args: ValidationArguments) => string) {
```

Comment: yup, that typescript magic. you can `or` on your return type and it can be any type that you can declare in TS it happens here to be a function or a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are reading it right, it's called a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). Union types allow the creation of types that can be either of the types in the union. You can use type-guards to narrow the types in a union:

```
let f : string|((args: ValidationArguments) => string);
if(typeof f === 'string') {
    f // is string
}else{
    f(null) // f is a function 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I really like the way you illustrated the proof in the answer!